# Comparing symbols in Lisp

Tags: lisp

Of course I am a novice but why doesn't this return `T`?

```
(eql (third '(0 1 'to 0 1)) 'to)
==> nil
```

But this does return the quoted `'to`.

```
(third '(0 1 'to 0 1))
'TO
```

As you might guess, none of the compare forms work, `eq`, `eql`, `equal`, `equalp`.

Answer (score 8):

Because

```
'TO
```

is not EQL to

```
TO
```

The first is a list with two symbols as elements. It's actually `(QUOTE TO)`.

The second is just a symbol.

```
? (EQL ''TO 'TO)
NIL
```

See:

```
? (equal (third '(0 1 'to 0 1)) ''TO)
T
```

You tried to quote a symbol in a literal list, which usually makes no sense, since literal lists are not evaluated inside.

Comment: You are right, it makes no sense to quote the to in the already quoted literal list so: (eq (third '(0 1 to 0 1)) 'to)=>T